# There is an error when I create a variable to store the widgets appbar for both material and cupertino

Tags: flutter

Here first I assign widget appbar to final variable because I want to use the preferredsize properties in my other widget to sizing it.
When I use cupertino and material both appbar styling I cannot use the preferredsize property.

So I make appbar preferredsizedwidget and that will show this type of error.

> A value of type 'Widget' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'PreferredSizeWidget'.
> Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'PreferredSizeWidget'.

How I casting the right-hand side?

Here is my build method

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final isLandscape = mediaQuery.orientation == Orientation.landscape;
    

    // ERROR CAUSE BY THIS VARIABLE
    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = Platform.isIOS? CupertinoNavigationBar() : AppBar(
      title: Text('Expense Planner'),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () => startNewTransactionInput(context),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );

    final listWidget = SizedBox(
      height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
              mediaQuery.padding.top -
              appBar.preferredSize.height) *
          0.75,
      child: TransactionList(_userTransactionList, _deleteTransaction),
    );

    final pageBody = SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          if (isLandscape)
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Show Chart'),
                // it abjust styling of the switch based on device palform
                Switch.adaptive(
                    value: _showChart,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _showChart = val;
                      });
                    })
              ],
            ),
          // weakly expense chart
          if (!isLandscape)
            SizedBox(
              height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                      mediaQuery.padding.top -
                      appBar.preferredSize.height) *
                  0.25,
              child: Chart(_recentTransactions),
            ),
          if (!isLandscape) listWidget,
          if (isLandscape)
            _showChart
                ? SizedBox(
                    height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                            mediaQuery.padding.top -
                            appBar.preferredSize.height) *
                        0.7,
                    child: Chart(_recentTransactions),
                  )
                : listWidget,
        ],
      ),
    );
    return Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoPageScaffold(
            child: pageBody,
            navigationBar: appBar, // insted of appbar here nevigationBart
          )
        : Scaffold(
            // title of the app
            appBar: appBar,
            // body of the app
            body: pageBody,
            floatingActionButton: Platform.isIOS
                ? Container()
                : FloatingActionButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () {
                      startNewTransactionInput(context);
                    },
                  ),
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
          );
  }
}
```

So how can I use preferredsize property and also use for both IOS and Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting using `as`

```
final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = Platform.isIOS? 
     CupertinoNavigationBar() as PreferredSizeWidget : // Casting here 
    AppBar(
      title: Text('Expense Planner'),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () => startNewTransactionInput(context),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ) as PreferredSizeWidget ; // Casting here
```

Comment: yaaa yes its' works 